# How to create Nix package/derivation with dependency that needs to be frequently updated

Tags: vim, immutability, nix, nixos

I am trying to use nix for building my development environment, While doing so and creating a customise vim with Ultisnips plugin installed I start to wonder where is the right place to store the snippets files on Nix system(nix package manager),

First Option:
Create a git/Github repo  for my snippets files and fetchFromGitHub into the Nix store.
But in this case, how could I update them constantly and easily without mutating the snippets dir in the nix store?

Second Option:
Reference from vimrc to outside of the nix store snippets folder.
In this case, the snippets folder is global, and all projects that are going to install my customized vim derivation will instantly have the most up to date files. This will come with a price of being less resilient and when I will install this derivation on a computer that does not hold this snippets folder I will get an error.

So I wonder what is the best approach for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use First Option, i.e. Create a git/Github repo. Indeed, 
vim plug-in manager, such as [Vundle.vim](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) use this method to install/update vim plugins.

Comment: What are you suggesting to do with a plugin that depends on a config that needs to be constantly updated and should be used in each installation of the derivation, like Snippets files in UltiSnip. How should they be updated?